# .catch is not resolving error and breaking the chain

Tags: node.js, promise, fs

I am trying to write a file. Some files are going to be written to incorrect paths.  For each file, I need to 
1. log to the console that the write is starting.
2. Write the file
3A if it is done writing, log to the console finished.
3B if it is a bad path, log to the console that the file failed

Right now, if it fails it writes both things to the console.

I've tried nesting the .thens, I've tried just call backs.

```
async function beginWrite(filename){
    console.log(`Creating file ${filename}`)
}

async function writeComplete(filename){
    console.log(`Finished creating file ${filename}`)
}

async function writeFile(path, filename){
    fs.writeFile(path + '/' + filename, 'this is a file', (error) => {
        if(error) {console.log(`File ${filename} failed to write`)}
    });
}

async function logAndWrite(path, filename){
    beginWrite(filename)
    .then( () => {
        writeFile(path, filename)
    }
    )
    .then(writeComplete(filename))
    .catch( (e) => {
        return console.log(`File ${filename} failed to write`)
    })
}
```

I expect

File 1 writing
File 1 complete
File 2 writing
File 2 failed to write
File 3 writing
File 3 Complete

Comment: You are not using `await`. Callbacks are different to promises, so you will want to either use the Promise interface, or if you use callbacks, wrap it in a new Promise, and resolve/reject in the callback, if the method you're using doesn't support Promises. Alternatively you could use write streams `createWriteStream` then you can simply do `stream.write('data')` and append data to your file.

Comment: yea, the callback was just an experimentation and is required for the fs.writeFile. I have taken it out.  Now nothing is being logged for the error and the catch is not working. I am not sure where I would put the await.

Comment: Use the [`path.join()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) to join paths, not string concatenation like `path + '/' + filename`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply sprinkle `async` over your function declarations and hope for magic to happen.

`async` is a way to deal with Promises. It requires that you `await` a Promise inside the async function, which in turn requires that you actually *have* a function that returns a Promise. You're not doing any of this.

First you need a function that returns a Promise. Node's native asynchronous functions use callbacks and return nothing, so if you want to use the native `fs.writeFile()` and return a Promise instead, you need to make a wrapper function. This process is called "promisification", and when done manually, it looks like this:

```
function writeFileAsync(file, data){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, err => {
            if (err) throw err; else resolve();
        })
    });
}
```

Node also has a utility to do the same thing in one step for any node-style asynchronous function ([`util.promisify(original)`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)).

```
const writeFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);
```

Now that there is something we can `await`, we can make an `async` function that awaits it (note that you *absolutely need* the try/catch block):

```
async function test() {
    try {
        let filename = 'some/file';
        console.log(`Creating file ${filename}`)
        await writeFileAsync(filename, 'this is a file');
        console.log(`Finished creating file ${filename}`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`File ${filename} failed to write`);
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

or we can use it with the equivalent regular `.then()` and `.catch()` semantics of Promises:

```
let filename = 'some/file';
console.log(`Creating file ${filename}`);
writeFileAsync(filename, 'this is a file')
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Finished creating file ${filename}`
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`File ${filename} failed to write`);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Ty, great explanation. I am still having trouble however getting the second console log of the try block, that says when it is finished, to run. My code now matches identically.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "getting the second console log". If you mean "the second console log does not seem to print anything" then your code does not match mine, because it definitely prints something. If you mean something else you must describe it better.